# Given two vertices, how to find the other two vertices of a rhombus?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, quadrilateral

> $A\;(-3,-4) $ and $ C \; (5,4)$ are the ends of the diagonal of a rhombus $ABCD$.
>
> Given that the side BC has gradient $\frac{5}{3}$; How could we find the coordinates of $B$ and hence of $D$?

#### Context

In a rhombus, both diagonals intersect at their midpoint. Therefore, it suffices to find $B$, from where $D$ can be found by using $B+D=A+C$. But how to find $B$? The slope of BC is known, but not its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B=(x,y)$ be the vertex below the given diagonal. Since $B$ is equidistant to $A$ and $C$:
$$
(x-5)^2+(y-4)^2=(x+3)^2+(y+4)^2.
$$
Simplifying the above yields
$$\tag{1}
1=x+y 
$$

Since $BC$ has gradient $5/3$
$$
{y-4\over x-5}={5\over3};
$$
whence $$\tag{2}3y-5x=-13.$$

By $(1)$, we have $y=1-x$. Substituting into $(2)$ gives $ 3(1-x)-5x=-13$. 
This gives $x=2$; and, from $(1)$, $y=-1$.

So $B=(2,-1)$.

Since the given diagonal has slope 1, and since $B$ is 5 units to the right and 3 units up from $A$, the forth vertex is   5 units up and 3 to the right of $A$, So $D=(0,1 )$.

Comment: I got the answer in a very much more long winded way by using simultaneous equations.

I don't understand the first part of the solution.  How is B equidistant to AC?

Comment: @dagda1 In a rhombus, all sides share a common length. $B$ and $A$ form one side of the given rhombus, $B$ and $C$ form another.